# sql to linq using distinct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following linq statement and cannot get it to work.

the code is:

```
(from ll in table1
 join l in table2
 on ll.LandlordId equals l.Id
 select((value, index) => new SelectListItem 
 {
      Value = value.Id.Tostring(),
      Text = value.FullName
 })).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.FullName).ToList()
```

The system is MVC and I am placing the result into a view model.

The view model is defined as `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

The error message is:

```
The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  
Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the problem has anything to do with `Distinct()`. What are the types of `ll.LandlordId` and `l.Id`? Additionally, your `select` clause looks completely broken to me - you can't use the overload where the selector function takes an index within a query expression, and it's not clear why you care, given that you're not using the index anyway.

Comment: (from ll in LandlordLists
                                   join l in Landlords
                                   on ll.LandlordId equals l.Id
                                   select(l)).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.FullName).ToList()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query expression is entirely broken at the moment - you're trying to use a mixture of query expressions and non-query-expressions. Additionally, constructing a `SelectListItem` and then using `Distinct` on that seems like a bad idea to me. You might try this:

```
var query = (from ll in table1
             join l in table2
             on ll.LandlordId equals l.Id
             select new { l.Id, ll.FullName })
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(x => x.FullName)
            .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest locally
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.FullName
            })
            .ToList();
```

I don't know if it will work - and I've made assumptions about where you want `Id` and `FullName` to come from - but it's at least rather more valid than your current query.

Comment: Thank you, you have helped greatly. The only issue was Value = x.Id, this needs to be x.Id.ToString(), but that is minor. Great job

Comment: @user1546400: Fixed that in the answer. Now would be a good time to read more about query expression syntax, to avoid future similar issues.